# How to set a transparent right border for vertical tabs in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create vertical tabs in Bootstrap 4. I am mostly done with it already, but would like to make the right border of the active tab transparent. I have tried to do so, but it doesn't seem to be working. You can find a working fiddle of what I have done so far, here: https://jsfiddle.net/mgryf1v5/4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="tabs-6ea2d5d5-9e96-4da1-89be-d8faff5a653d" role="tabpanel">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-left" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-1" aria-controls="tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-selected="false">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-2" aria-controls="tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-3" aria-controls="tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-4" aria-controls="tab-4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#tab-5" aria-controls="tab-5" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 5</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-1" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Content 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Content 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Content 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-4" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Content 4
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-5" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    Content 5
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-tabs-left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.nav-tabs-left .nav-link.active, .nav-tabs-left .nav-item.show .nav-link {
    border-color: #dee2e6 transparent #dee2e6 #dee2e6;
}
```

**EDIT**

Final CSS based on @Rishi Raj's comments:

```
.nav-tabs-left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-right: unset !important;
}
.nav-tabs-left .nav-link {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important; 
}
.nav-tabs-left .nav-link.active, .nav-tabs-left .nav-item.show .nav-link {
    border-color: #dee2e6 #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6 !important;
}
```

and a fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/1rq4wv3z/

Comment: .nav-tabs-left{ border-right: transparent !important}

Comment: @RishiRaj Thank you, but I only want the "active" tab to have a transparent right border. Not all of the tabs.

Comment: .nav-link.active {
  border-color: #dee2e6 #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6 !important;
}
.nav-tabs-left{
  border-right: unset !important;
}
.nav-link {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

Comment: put these three and let me know if this works.

Comment: @RishiRaj That did it. Thank you. I will update my post with the final solution. If you then add it as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.nav-link.active { 
  border-color: #dee2e6 #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6 !important;
}
.nav-tabs-left { 
  border-right: unset !important; 
} 
.nav-link { 
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.nav-tabs-left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-right-color: transparent ;
}
.nav-link {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd !important;
} 
.nav-link.active {
border-color: #dee2e6 #fff #dee2e6 #dee2e6 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, but @RishiRaj already helped me find the answer.